# Update table with merge in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with values associated to the sells of (almost a million) different products by day, and I have to create the collection with the aggregation per week. I do it with the following (working) query.

Brief explanation:
I filter the dates I want to use in the query.
I convert the weird date format to a real date.
I group by name of the object, year and week, getting the sum per week.
I group again by name to have all dates in the same document.
I save it to a table.

```
    [
  {
    $match:
      /**
       * query: The query in MQL.
       */
      {
        $and: [
          {
            "_id.date": {
              $gte: "20220103",
            },
          },
          {
            "_id.date": {
              $lte: "20230122",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
  },
  {
    $project:
      /**
       * specifications: The fields to
       *   include or exclude.
       */
      {
        _id: 1,
        realDate: {
          $dateFromString: {
            dateString: "$_id.date",
            format: "%Y%m%d",
          },
        },
        count: 1,
      },
  },
  {
    $group:
      /**
       * _id: The id of the group.
       * fieldN: The first field name.
       */
      {
        _id: {
          name: "$_id.name",
          year: {
            $isoWeekYear: "$realDate",
          },
          week: {
            $isoWeek: "$realDate",
          },
        },
        total: {
          $sum: "$count",
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $group:
      /**
       * _id: The id of the group.
       * fieldN: The first field name.
       */
      {
        _id: "$_id.name",
        dates: {
          $addToSet: {
            year: "$_id.year",
            week: "$_id.week",
            count: "$total",
          },
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $merge:
      /**
       * into: The target collection.
       * on: Fields to  identify.
       * let: Defined variables.
       * whenMatched: Action for matching docs.
       * whenNotMatched: Action for non-matching docs.
       */
      {
        into: "dataPerWeek",
        on: "_id",
      },
  },
]
```

That works, and generate documents like:

```
{

  "_id": "myProduct",
  "dates": [
    {
      "year": {
        "$numberLong": "2022"
      },
      "week": 52,
      "count": 10
    },
    {
      "year": {
        "$numberLong": "2022"
      },
      "week": 50,
      "count": 6
    },
    {
      "year": {
        "$numberLong": "2022"
      },
      "week": 49,
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "year": {
        "$numberLong": "2022"
      },
      "week": 51,
      "count": 5
    },
    {
      "year": {
        "$numberLong": "2023"
      },
      "week": 1,
      "count": 5
    },
    {
      "year": {
        "$numberLong": "2023"
      },
      "week": 2,
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "year": {
        "$numberLong": "2023"
      },
      "week": 3,
      "count": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I would want now to update this list every week adding only the new elements to the array (or creating a new object if it does not exist. But, if I repeat the merge query above limiting the dates to the last week, it basically removes all other data points. Is is possible to do this "update" with a single query?

Answer (score 0):

You should store date values as `Date` objects. Storing date values as string is a design flaw.

Your pipeline can be shorter and your `$merge` stage would be like this:

```
[
   {
      $match: {
         "_id.date": {
            $gte: ISODate("2022-01-03"),
            $lte: ISODate("2023-01-22"),
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            name: "$_id.name",
            week: { $dateTrunc: { date: "_id.date", unit: "week", startOfWeek: "monday" } }
         },
         total: { $sum: "$count" },
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$_id.name",
         dates: {
            $push: { // $push should be faster than $addToSet, result is the same
               year: { $isoWeekYear: "$_id.week" },
               week: { $isoWeek: "$_id.week" },
               count: "$total",
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $merge: {
         into: "dataPerWeek",
         on: "_id",
         whenMatched: [
            { $set: { dates: { $concatArrays: ["$dates", "$$new.dates"] } } }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

The `dates` elements are simply concatenated. If you like to update existing elements then you need to iterate over all elements with `$map`